# Codeigniter 3 ajax calculating from another input using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3

So the idea is to manipulate the value that is delivered by Ajax. This value should be divided by 20 and the result should be multiplied by the value from #nilai_hari input.
Here's my code

```
// trigger
<select class="form-control" id="id_anggota" name="id_anggota">
    <option>-Pilih Karyawan</option>
    <?php $no=1; foreach ($listAnggota as $l) {?>
        <option value="<?php echo $l->id_anggota; ?>">
            <?php echo $l->nama_lengkap; ?>
        </option>
        <?php $no++; }?>
</select>
// the effected
<select class="tunjangan_makan form-control total_tunjangan nominal" id="tunjangan_makan" name="tunjangan_makan"></select>
// another trigger
<input type="text" id="nilai_hari" name="nilai_hari" class="form-control">
```

And here's the script

```
$('#id_anggota').change(function() {
    var id = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>hrd/penggajian/get_subpenggajian",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            id: id
        },
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            var html = '';
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if (data[i].flat_tunjangan == 1) {
                    html += '<option value="' + data[i].tunjangan_makan + '">' + number_format(data[i].tunjangan_makan, 0, '', '.') + '</option>';
                } else {
                    $('#tunjangan_makan', '#nilai_hari').keyup(function() {
                        var nilai_hari = $("#nilai_hari").val(),
                            makan = ((data[i].tunjangan_makan / 20) * nilai_hari)
                        html += '<option value="' + makan + '">' + number_format(makan, 0, '', '.') + '</option>';
                    })
                }
            }
            $('.tunjangan_makan').html(html);
        }
    });
});
```

So, the value of the data in which flat_tunjangan is 0 must be calculated from another input. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. You should call other input onkey event and call same ajax request again and remove that onkey event inside  $('#id_anggota').change().

```js
$('#id_anggota').change(function(){
        var id=$(this).val();
        
        // perform ajax and get data
        var data = [{'flat_tunjangan': '1', 'tunjangan_makan': '20'}, {'flat_tunjangan': '0', 'tunjangan_makan': '30'}];
        
        var html = '';
        var i;
        for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
          if(data[i].flat_tunjangan == 1){
            html += '<option value="'+data[i].tunjangan_makan+'">'+data[i].tunjangan_makan+'</option>';
          } else {
              var nilai_hari  = $("#nilai_hari").val(), 
              makan = ((data[i].tunjangan_makan/20)*nilai_hari)
              
              if (makan != '') {
                html += '<option value="'+makan+'">'+makan+'</option>';
              }
          }
        }
        $('.tunjangan_makan').html(html);
 });
 
 $("#nilai_hari").keyup(function(){
    var nilai_hari = $(this).val();
    
    // again do ajax reqeust and fetch data using selected tunjangan_makan id
    var id = $('#id_anggota').val();
    var data = [{'flat_tunjangan': '1', 'tunjangan_makan': '20'}, {'flat_tunjangan': '0', 'tunjangan_makan': '30'}];
    
    var html = '';
    var i;
    for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
      if(data[i].flat_tunjangan == 1){
        html += '<option value="'+data[i].tunjangan_makan+'">'+data[i].tunjangan_makan+'</option>';
      } else {
          var nilai_hari  = $("#nilai_hari").val(), 
          makan = ((data[i].tunjangan_makan/20)*nilai_hari)

          if (makan != '') {
            html += '<option value="'+makan+'">'+makan+'</option>';
          }
      }
    }
    $('.tunjangan_makan').html(html);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="id_anggota" name="id_anggota">
    <option value="1">Test 1</option>
    <option value="2">Test 2</option>
</select>

<select class="tunjangan_makan form-control total_tunjangan nominal" id="tunjangan_makan" name="tunjangan_makan"></select>

<input type="text" id="nilai_hari" name="nilai_hari" class="form-control">
```

Comment: I'll try, wait a moment

Comment: can you explain what are the value 20 and 30 for?

Comment: These are response from your ajax request. I just use a sample static response according to your data

Comment: 20 and 30 will be value of "tunjangan_makan" field in your ajax response

Comment: Thanks, it works though I add some code to make it smoother